# Mongodb Aggregate Using Group And Getting Count Of Properties Which Equal Condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to implement the following query as efficient as possible so I'm using the Mongodb `Aggregation` framework.

I have a collection called `mydevices` which contains documents each representing a device of the following format:

```
{
  BUILDING: 'stringValue',
  DEVICECLASS: 'stringValue',
}
```

The output which I'm trying to achieve is an array for each `BUILDING` containing the count of devices per `DEVICECLASS` in each category e.g.

```
'building xy': {
   'mobile phone': 5,
   'destkop': 3
}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
  collection.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $group:{ // group by building
                    _id: {BUILDING},
                    DEVCLASS: {DEVCLASS} // save devclass as property
                }
            }
        ]
    )
```

It seems like the `$count` operator is not helpfull in my case?

> $count
>   Returns a document that contains a count of the number of documents input to the stage.

I have read the documentation but I'm stuck now. How can I achieve the result?

Comment: Try `collection.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $group:{ 
                    _id: {BUILDING:"$BUILDING",DEVICECLASS:"$DEVICECLASS"} 
                    COUNT: {$sum:1}
                }
            }
        ]
    )`

Comment: @Veeram Using this I only get the overall count of all devices without knowing the count of devices in a given deviceclass for a location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{"building" : "$building", "deviceclass":"$deviceclass"},count:{$sum:1} }},
       {$group:{_id:{"building" : "$_id.building" },result : {$push : {"deviceclass" : "$_id.deviceclass","count" : "$count"}}}},
        {$project : {"building" : "$_id.building" , "deviceclass" : "$result",_id:0}}
    ])
```

You will get:

```
{
    "building" : "building xy",
    "deviceclass" : [ 
        {
            "deviceclass" : "mobile phone",
            "count" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "deviceclass" : "destkop",
            "count" : 1.0
        }
    ] 
}
```

Comment: Ty, it is working. Some comments about how it works would be nice, so I can follow the aggregation steps...

Comment: first group on building and deviceclass so data is grouped in building and deviceclass wise..after that group on building so same deviceclass with same building is shown in result